Bash named pipe blocking
For some reason, this bash script never gets to echo "after cat", but does get past echo "before cat".
rm pipe
mkfifo pipe

echo "before server"

cd backend
node bin/www > pipe &
cd ..


echo "before cat"

server_output=$(cat pipe) # seems to get hung up here

echo "after cat"

echo "$server_output"

# [bash to check the server output here and print it conditionally]

I understand that pipes need to have both ends open in order to not block, but I thought I've done this by including the '&' symbol in node bin/www > pipe &.
I've tried using head (with --lines=1 and without) instead of cat to no avail.

My guess is that the node command never terminates. Did you check this?

Does the node command produce any output at all? Have you tested that?

thanks, but yes, they do.  facepalm the two pipes are in different directories.

How did you  check that node terminated?

The reason your program stalls is because its reading from the pipe but nothing is being written to it.
mkfifo pipe creates a FIFO with the name pipe in the current directory.
However, you change directories after creating the FIFO file:
cd backend

You are in a different directory, and the FIFO file isn't going to be there.
Instead you need to pipe your command to the actual path of the FIFO file:
node bin/www > ../pipe &


Interesting point; I missed this, But shouldn't in this case the shell report an error for the input redirection <pipe?

Bash will create a new file if one doesn't already exist when redirecting output. So the output is redirected to a new file in that directory with name pipe.

@MaximillianBallard : I missed the cd before the OP is writing to the pipe. I have only notice the cd after.
